# Contraseña no registrada al guardar un nuevo usuario en un Django con un modelo de usuario personalizado

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

Cuando intento registrar un usuario, adaptando lo que aprendí de [Building a Custom User Model with Extended Fields youtube tutorial](https://youtu.be/Ae7nc1EGv-A?t=2029), no puedo iniciar sesión después a pesar de proporcionar la misma contraseña:

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.conf import settings
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from .forms import TodoForm
from .models import Todo
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'todo/home.html')

def signupuser(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'todo/signupuser.html', {'form':UserCreationForm()})
    else:
        if request.POST['password1'] == request.POST['password2']:
            try:
                db = get_user_model()
                user = db.objects.create_user(request.POST['email'], request.POST['username'], 
                                            request.POST['firstname'], request.POST['company'], request.POST['mobile_number'], 
                                            password=request.POST['password1'])
                user.save()
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('currenttodos')
```

El usuario sigue registrado pero no puedo iniciar sesión con la contraseña proporcionada ... ¿Cuál podría ser la razón?

Aquí está mi modelo de usuario personalizado:

`models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager


class CustomAccountManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_superuser(self, email, user_name, first_name, password, **other_fields):

        other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if other_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(
                'Superuser must be assigned to is_staff=True.')
        if other_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(
                'Superuser must be assigned to is_superuser=True.')

        return self.create_user(email, user_name, first_name, password, **other_fields)

    def create_user(self, email, user_name, first_name,  company, mobile_number, password, **other_fields):

        if not email:
            raise ValueError(('You must provide an email address'))

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, user_name=user_name, first_name=first_name, 
                        company=company, mobile_number=mobile_number, password=password, **other_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

class Newuser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(('email address'), unique=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = CustomAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['user_name', 'first_name', 'mobile_number']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_name
```

`settings.py`

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'todo.NewUser'
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/ creo que debes seguir la guía, django.contrib.Auth contiene el objeto User, si tu creas uno no sirve, debes utilizar el del sistema